# Treat Header to Data in Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am using a package to read in a table from a pdf.  The source table is badly formed so I have a series of inconsistently formatted tables I have to clean on the backend (so reading with header "none" is not an option).  The first row, which is data, is being treated as a header.  How can I get that first row treated as a data row so I can add a proper header?  (output below truncated as it has numerous columns)

```
    **Asia  Afghanistan 35,939**
0   Asia    Bahrain     972      
1   Asia    Bhutan      1,910    
2   Asia    Brunei      111      
3   Asia    Burma       20,078   
4   Asia    Cambodia    179,662
```

Goal is for the "Afganistan" header row to drop to index 0 and then label Continent, Country, Total.

Thanks in advance, this has driven me nuts

Note in request to actual code, see below, the issue is in Tables[1]

```
import pandas as pd
import tabula
file = "https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Diversity-Visa/DVStatistics/DV-applicant-entrants-by-country-2019-2021.pdf"
 
tables = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages = "all", multiple_tables = True)
file = "https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Diversity-Visa/DVStatistics/DV-applicant-entrants-by-country-2019-2021.pdf"
 
tables = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages = "all", multiple_tables = True)
tables[1].head()

# note I tried to use zip  this only creates a multilevel header, not the desire effect of pushing the current header down as data and adding a new header

ColumnNames =['Region','Foreign State of Chargeability','FY 2019 Entrants','FY 2019 Derivatives','FY 2019 Total','FY 2020 Entrants','FY 2020 Derivatives','FY 2020 Total','FY 2021 Entrants','FY 2021 Derivatives','FY 2021 Total']
tables[1].columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    zip(ColumnNames, 
        tables[1].columns))
tables[1].reset_index(0)
tables[1].head()
```

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it.  Perhaps not the most elegant solution.  Created a one-column data frame from the "Column labels" (which was actually data) where it has the real column labels, added those labes to the original frame(which over writes that row), then concat

```
ColumnNames =['Region','Foreign State of Chargeability','FY 2019 Entrants','FY 2019 Derivatives','FY 2019 Total','FY 2020 Entrants','FY 2020 Derivatives','FY 2020 Total','FY 2021 Entrants','FY 2021 Derivatives','FY 2021 Total']
First_Row = tables[1].columns.values.tolist()
#make one column dataframe
dTemp= pd.DataFrame(First_Row)
dTemp=dTemp.transpose()
dTemp.columns=ColumnNames
# we can now write over fist column with column labels
tables[1].columns=ColumnNames
tables[1] = pd.concat([dTemp,tables[1]], axis=0,ignore_index=True)
```